# Namespace naming for general Purpose libraries - Personal or Company name?

Tags: .net, namespaces, naming-conventions

I'm currently writing some general purpose .net libraries that contain usual helper classes.
For example, to deal with string encryption/decryption, saving to configuration files, etc...

Right now, I'm the sole developer of the company I'm working in, and it doesn't look like it is going to change soon: so I wouldn't "steal" anybody code.
However, it is likely that I would leave the company at some point.

Like most developers, it is more than likely that I would like to reuse these libraries that I would have built over time, in my new company, since they would contain company-agnostic code.

If I name them after the current company, I will need to change the namespace and recompile all the new libraries, which may turn out to be time consuming and error-prone if there is a significant number of them.

I would also want to use these libraries for some personal projects and extend them during my spare time as well and working on those projects.

Naming them after my name though seems very egocentric though. If I joined a new company, I don't think I would like to have the name of the previous developer in almost all the code files.

On the other hand, something like "Common.Library" seems a bit too generic.

I would like to know how you developers changing companies relatively often are tackling this?
Being the sole developer, I'm very flexible regarding the code-design decision but I would still want to respect the best practices and provide a decent code-base for my successor.

**PS: I have checked regarding IP with my boss and they don't mind as long the code I'm reusing doesn't contain business logic, so please keep the comments/answers technical and not legal.**

Comment: If there's no IP issues then you can call them what you like.

Comment: Indeed, but I feel I should also consider things from the point of view of the potential person who would come after me... as we all know, when we start in a new company and have to take over an existing code-base, there are all kinds of things which can bug us to no-end and I would prefer trying to be a good citizen.

Comment: It still doesn't matter. There has to be a namespace, to the person coming after you it's just one more thing they have to learn. **What** the namespace is makes very little difference.

Comment: Don't waste too much time wringing your hands over this. Name it whatever you want and be done with it. Even more important than choosing the perfect name is [choosing a reasonably *short* name](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/01/a-modest-namespace-proposal.html). The primary purpose of namespaces is to provide uniqueness, to prevent your code from colliding with others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no general answer to your question.
Why not just use your initials, if you don't want your full name in the libraries?

Something like `kd.Common.Library`.

Comment: Usual naming convention for namespaces is to use pascal casing (in case OP decides to go for this approach). In that case, `KD.Common.Library` would seem more appropriate.

Comment: I know, but I don't like the looks of `Kd.Common.Library` or `KD.Common.Library`. As with this whole question, this is purely a matter of personal preference...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, which I had also already considered... the problem is that using initials still seems out-of-place and egocentric. Also, the next developer who would come after me could wonder what KD means... I can indeed name them however I like but I would also like to view things from the "next developer's" point of view...

Comment: @KharlosDominguez: There is no answer to that question. Do whatever feels right for you!

Comment: What do you think about Common.* etc? I think it would be a good alternative but breaking the generally accepted best practice of starting namespaces names with a personally identifiable information (company or person). .Net Framework has namespaces like System.* of course, though.

Comment: @KharlosDominguez: I wouldn't do it, because this is too general, you might run into problems with other libraries.

Answer (score 1):

> If I name them after the current company, I will need to change the namespace [...]

If there are no IP issues, it is not like you will really *need* to change it. This will purely depend on your personal preference in that case.

I find this case like using any other third-party library, even if its license allows you to change its source. As long as you can reuse this code base later, namespace naming will be completely secondary IMHO.